# addEventListener error with jQuery 1.x and IE8

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8

An aplication using jQuery 1.12.3 returns an error on IE8:

```
Object doesn't support property or method 'addEventListener'
```

I know there's many other questions about this particular error but the answer is always to use jQuery 1.x, which I'm already using and the error is raised within jQuery's code.

Any idea on what might be the problem?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: *"...and the error is raised within jQuery's code"* Can you show your code calling jQuery that triggers that? Ideally a [mcve]? Because jQuery 1.12.3 should be compatible with IE8. (Are you **quite** sure you're not using jQuery 2.x?)

Comment: [Works for me](http://output.jsbin.com/gapozafovi) (on IE8).

Comment: @T.J.Crowder actually no. A colleague hard copied a jQuery 2.x in the deployed site directory and ASP.NET automatically bundled **that** version despite not being in the original published project. Sorry for taking your time, but your **quite** was helpful. :)

Comment: Ah, that explains it. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you're accidentally using jQuery 2.x or similar rather than jQuery 1.12.3. 1.12.3 knows better than to try to use `addEventListener` on IE8, but as of jQuery 2.x, they dropped support for IE8 and earlier.

Comment: Correct. I'm accepting this answer cause you helped me find the problem. Posted a different answer for the complete explanation.

Answer (score 0):

A colleague hard copied a jQuery 2.x .js in the deployed site directory and ASP.NET automatically bundled **that** version despite not being in the original published project.

Deleted the file from the Scripts folder and problem solved. ASP.NET is now bundling jQuery 1.12.3. Sorry for taking your time on such a trivial mistake.

Thanks for your help!